# Tkinter GUI RFID Reader

Tags: python, tkinter, rfid

I'm making a gui for my rfid reader but when i run the program it only operates on the shell window and does not open a tkinter gui window. I'm kind of new with python and it's gui so can anybody help me. even a tutorial for a solution to my problem can help. here is my code. thank you for the help.

```
from tkinter import *
import binascii
import socket
import time
import signal
import sys

import Adafruit_PN532 as PN532

root = Tk(className="Team Baboy") 
root.geometry("800x480")
welcome = Label(root,text="Welcome to Hog Traceability System")
welcome.pack()
welcome.config(font=("Gothic", 18))
back = Frame(width=800, height=480)
back.pack()


instruction = Label(master=back, text='Tap your Authorization Card')
instruction.pack()
instruction.config(font=("Gothic", 30))
instruction.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=150)

CS   = 18
MOSI = 23
MISO = 24
SCLK = 25

CARD_KEY = [0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF]

Delay = 1

HEADER = b'BG'

def close(signal, frame):
         sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close)

pn532 = PN532.PN532(cs=CS, sclk=SCLK, mosi=MOSI, miso=MISO)
pn532.begin()
pn532.SAM_configuration()

print('PN532 NFC RFID 13.56MHz Card Reader')

while True:
    uid = pn532.read_passive_target()
    if uid is None:
        continue
    print('')
    print('Card UID 0x{0}'.format(binascii.hexlify(uid)))
    if not pn532.mifare_classic_authenticate_block(uid, 4, PN532.MIFARE_CMD_AUTH_B, CARD_KEY):
        print('Failed to authenticate with card!')
        continue
    data = pn532.mifare_classic_read_block(4)
    if data is None:
        print('Failed to read data from card!')
        continue
    if data[0:2] !=  HEADER:
        print('Card is not written with proper block data!')
        continue
    print('User Id: {0}'.format(int(data[2:8].decode("utf-8"), 16)))




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using? For versions earlier than python3 it is Tkinter, but in Python 3 it is tkinter

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a tkinter issue, rather than one related to RFID. I would start by getting the GUI to work before adding RFID functionality.

Here, I have commented out all the RFID code to leave just the tkinter code. I then initialised `Tk()` *without* arguments, as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html).

```
from Tkinter import *
import binascii
import socket
import time
import signal
import sys

# import Adafruit_PN532 as PN532

root = Tk()
root.className = "TeamBadoy"
# root = Tk(className="Team Baboy")
root.geometry("800x480")
welcome = Label(root,text="Welcome to Hog Traceability System")
welcome.pack()
welcome.config(font=("Gothic", 18))
back = Frame(width=800, height=480)
back.pack()


instruction = Label(master=back, text='Tap your Authorization Card')
instruction.pack()
instruction.config(font=("Gothic", 30))
instruction.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=150)

CS   = 18
MOSI = 23
MISO = 24
SCLK = 25

# CARD_KEY = [0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF]

Delay = 1

HEADER = b'BG'

# def close(signal, frame):
#          sys.exit(0)
#
# signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close)
#
# pn532 = PN532.PN532(cs=CS, sclk=SCLK, mosi=MOSI, miso=MISO)
# pn532.begin()
# pn532.SAM_configuration()

print('PN532 NFC RFID 13.56MHz Card Reader')

# while True:
    # uid = pn532.read_passive_target()
    # if uid is None:
    #     continue
    # print('')
    # print('Card UID 0x{0}'.format(binascii.hexlify(uid)))
    # if not pn532.mifare_classic_authenticate_block(uid, 4, PN532.MIFARE_CMD_AUTH_B, CARD_KEY):
    #     print('Failed to authenticate with card!')
    #     continue
    # data = pn532.mifare_classic_read_block(4)
    # if data is None:
    #     print('Failed to read data from card!')
    #     continue
    # if data[0:2] !=  HEADER:
    #     print('Card is not written with proper block data!')
    #     continue
    # print('User Id: {0}'.format(int(data[2:8].decode("utf-8"), 16)))




root.mainloop()
# while True:
#     tk.update_idletasks()
#     tk.update()
#     sleep(0.01)
```

This results in a GUI window displaying; it does not actually *do* anything yet, but it does show up!

[image: Screenshot of GUI window produced by above code]

On [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop) the suggestion is that, rather than using `mainloop()`, you might want to consider explicitly stating;

```
while True:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Actually, if you can, you should use the Tkinter event loop. It forces the developer to write event-driven code, which is easier to extend (using [`after`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/after.htm), for example).